# Modrewrite Rewrite Rule Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

so I have the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-search-results.html?$ search.php?search=$2&page=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to have something like this

```
/1-test1-test2-search-results.html
```

rewrite to

```
search.php?search=test1-test2&page=1
```

although it's rewriting it as

```
search.php?search=test2&page=1-test1
```

anyone know how I can get it the way I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use lazy Matching

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-(.*)-search-results.html?$ search.php?search=$2&page=$1 [L]
```